# Fontello ins't work on mozilla firefox, and works on Chrome and IE on the same computer

Tags: html, css

My problem is that Fontello doesn't work properly on Firefox on my computer. the console displays an error:

> Blocked request to a resource of another origin: the "Same Origin Policy" policy does not allow loading of remote resources from "file: /// C: /Users/Wojtek/Desktop/projekt/font/fontello.woff? 49170314" (non-HTTP CORS request ).

and

> Blocked request to a resource of another origin: the "Same Origin Policy" policy does not allow loading of remote resources from "file: /// C: /Users/Wojtek/Desktop/projekt/font/fontello.ttf? 49170314" (non-HTTP CORS request ).

Comment: Hi Wojbuk and welcome. Can you show the HTML or CSS code where you are trying to load the font? How are you trying to load the font?

Comment: sure wait a few minutes

Comment: I have a problem and I don't know haw to do this. wait my friend

Comment: Edit the post and copy + paste the code.

Comment: I can't do this why it tells me: Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Comment: Oke, copy paste code then select the complete code and press button with brackets: "{ }".

Comment: Here you are...I have no idea what to do

Comment: Do you know how to install a web server (software)? https://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/ You need a web server install it on your computer. Create a new "hostname" and select the current location of your folder and run the server.

Comment: Okay thanks Pauria Mosavi. It works now. I always get in a state when something doesn't work. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Blog na temat ciekawych publikacji z dziedziny filozofii, omówienie wybranych tekstów najsłynniejszych autorów!">
    <meta name="keywords" content="filozofia, blok, książki, przemyślenia">
    <meta name="author" content="Wojciech Bukowski">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1">
    <title>Philosophia Blog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontello.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700&display=swap" > 
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1 class="logo">Philosophia Blog</h1>
        <nav>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Strona Główna</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Pierwszy raz tutaj?</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dlaczego filozofia</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">O autorze</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <article>
            <section>
                <div class="categories">
                    <header>
                        <h1>Witaj w świecie filozofii!</h1>
                        <p> Czy jesteś fanem filozofii? Lubisz świat idei? Ciekawią Cię sposoby interpretowania świata przez ludzi? Jeśli tak, to zapraszam do przygotowanych przeze mnie artukułów inspirowanych publikacjami znanych filozofów. </p>
                    </header>
                    <div class="authors">
                        <figure>
                            <a href="#"><img src="img/alan-watts.jpg" alt="Alan Watts"></a>
                        </figure>
                        <figcaption>Alan Watts</figcaption>
                    </div>
                    <div class="authors">
                        <figure>
                            <a href="#"><img src="img/de-mello.jpg" alt="De Mello"></a>
                        </figure>
                        <figcaption>De Mello</figcaption>
                    </div>
                    <div class="authors">
                        <figure>
                            <a href="#"><img src="img/emerson.jpg" alt="Emerson"></a>
                        </figure>
                        <figcaption>Emerson</figcaption>
                    </div>
                    <div class="authors">
                        <figure>
                            <a href="#"><img src="img/kant.jpg" alt="Emanuel Kant"></a>
                        </figure>
                        <figcaption>Emanuel Kant</figcaption>
                    </div>
                    <div class="authors">
                        <figure>
                            <a href="#"><img src="img/nietzsche.jpg" alt="Nietzsche"></a>
                        </figure>
                        <figcaption>Nietzsche</figcaption>
                    </div>
                    <div class="authors">
                        <figure>
                            <a href="#"><img src="img/platon.jpg" alt="Platon"></a>
                        </figure>
                        <figcaption>Platon</figcaption>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section id="newest">
                <div class="entries">
                    <header>
                        <h1>Najnowsze wpisy</h1>
                        <p> Poniżej znajdziesz trzy ostatnio opublikowane artykuły- dzięki temu można sprawdzić, czy na blogu pojawiło się coś nowego. Wpisy zazwyczaj pojawiają się we wtorki i piątki, o nowościach informują także na swoim Twitterze.</p>
                    </header>
                    <div class="entry">
                        <div class="entryimg">
                            <img src="img/alan-watts.jpg" alt="Alan Watts">
                        </div>
                        <div class="entrytxt">
                            <h2>Antony de Mello: Poszukiwanie akceptacji</h2>
                            <p>Ktoś kiedyś pięknie to ujął: życie to coś, co przydarza się nam podczas gdy jesteśmy zajęci układaniem planów. Jesteśmy zajęci imponowaniem wszystim wokół, dbaniem o to, by na pewno zostać dobrze odebranym. Porozmawiajmy o nałogu poszukiwania akceptacji</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="entry">
                        <div class="entryimg">
                            <img src="img/alan-watts.jpg" alt="Alan Watts">
                        </div>
                        <div class="entrytxt">
                            <h2>Antony de Mello: Poszukiwanie akceptacji</h2>
                            <p>Ktoś kiedyś pięknie to ujął: życie to coś, co przydarza się nam podczas gdy jesteśmy zajęci układaniem planów. Jesteśmy zajęci imponowaniem wszystim wokół, dbaniem o to, by na pewno zostać dobrze odebranym. Porozmawiajmy o nałogu poszukiwania akceptacji</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="entry">
                        <div class="entryimg">
                            <img src="img/alan-watts.jpg" alt="Alan Watts">
                        </div>
                        <div class="entrytxt">
                            <h2>Antony de Mello: Poszukiwanie akceptacji</h2>
                            <p>Ktoś kiedyś pięknie to ujął: życie to coś, co przydarza się nam podczas gdy jesteśmy zajęci układaniem planów. Jesteśmy zajęci imponowaniem wszystim wokół, dbaniem o to, by na pewno zostać dobrze odebranym. Porozmawiajmy o nałogu poszukiwania akceptacji</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section>

                    <div class="contact">
                        <header>
                            <h1>Kontakt z autorem</h1>
                            <p> Jeśli masz ochotę podyskutować, zaproponować temat wpisu lub nawiązać współpracę reklamową- zapraszam do kontaktu mailowego, proszę jednak o wyrozumiałość co do czasu udzielenia przeze mnie odpowiedzi.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="bluebatton">Nawiązanie współpracy</a>
                        </header>
                    </div>

            </section>
        </article>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <div class="socials">
            <div class="socialdivs">
                <div class="fb">
                    <i class="icon-facebook"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="yt">
                    <i class="icon-youtube"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="tw">
                    <i class="icon-twitter"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="gplus">
                    <i class="icon-gplus"></i>
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
body
{
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color: #2F3336;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #efefef;
}



h1.logo
{
    font-size: 44px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color:#ddd;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

nav
{
    background-color: #1c74b2;
    text-align: center;
}

.menu
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    min-height: 40px;
    line-height: 200%;
}

.menu > li
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    border-right: 1px dashed #0a2b42;
    min-height: 40px;
}

.menu > li:first-child
{
    border-left: 1px dashed #0a2b42;
}

.menu a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

.menu a:hover
{
    color: #0a2b42;
}

.categories 
{
    width: 950px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px;
}

h1
{
    font-size: 44px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #39a5f1;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.authors
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.authors a
{
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.authors a:hover
{
    opacity: 1;
}

figure
{
    margin: 8px;
    padding:0;
}

figcaption
{
    margin-top: 8px;
    padding: 0;
}

.entries 
{
    width: 950px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 80px;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
#newest
{
    background-color: #191d21;
}

.entry
{
    background-color: #222930;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: justify;
    margin-top: 40px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.entryimg
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 110px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.entryimg img
{
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;

}

.entrytxt
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 750px;
    font-size: 15px;
}


h2
{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #39a5f1;
}

.contact p
{
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.contact
{
    width: 950px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-bottom: 80px;
}

.bluebatton
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #efefef;
    background-color: #1c74b2;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 19px;
}

.bluebatton:hover
{
    background-color: #196499;
}

.socials
{
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #292929;
}

.socialdivs
{
    width: 1000px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.fb
{
    width: 250px;
    height: 155px;
    float:left;
}

.fb:hover
{
    background-color: #4668b3;
}

.yt
{
    width: 250px;
    height: 155px;
    float:left;
}

.yt:hover
{
    background-color: #d94348;
}

.tw
{
    width: 250px;
    height: 155px;
    float:left;
}

.tw:hover
{
    background-color: #3095d3;
}

.gplus
{
    width: 250px;
    height: 155px;
    float:left;
}

.gplus:hover
{
    background-color: #d95333;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you already solved your problem but I had a very similar issue. In my case, I went to Firefox about config page and then disabled privacy.file_unique_origin (double click) option. I hope it will help